# Wordpress link structure

Tags: php, wordpress, api, permalinks

Its been a while since I worked anything with wordpress, so I might be doing smth wrong..

So, I am working on some maintenance, and I have a task to rewrite this:

```
www.page.com/category/?id=12345
```

to

```
www.page.com/category/12345
```

or

```
www.page.com/category/TITLE_12345
```

Also, `www.page.com/category/` is actually a page where we show results from an API endpoint, where we fetch data by either id or title (both are uniqe).

So, I managed to change from "query" to "path", but it only works for number, not for string. If I try to do it via string, I get 404...

Also, I manage to do the necessary changes to the API, that is all ok and working.

So, my question is how do I do this succesfully? How can I add the rule(s) to rewrite urls so both int and string would be accepted.

Edit: All I did so far was on the part where url is built (which is dynamic, as it is intended to external API call), I removed the ?id= part and I am passing only number (which works)..And also, permalinks are set to numbers ([www.page.com/archive/123](http://www.page.com/archive/123)).

thx

Comment: So what is your question? Show us how you wrote URL rules

Comment: I did not do anything special. All I did was on the part where url is built, I removed the ?id= part and I am passing only number (which works)..And also, permalinks are set to numbers (www.page.com/archive/123)

Comment: Does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850933/wordpress-plug-ins-how-to-add-custom-seo-friendly-url-handles

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from **.htaccess** rewrite rules or use wordpress functions : **add_rewrite_rule**